# Choose more words in a token

Tags: batch-file, random, token

I am trying to make a random event that chooses from a list of words and sentences. Whenever the event happens it only displays the first word in every line. How do I make it so that it will display the entire line?

Here is the batch file.

```
set /a groceryrandom=%random%%%16
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (groceryevents.txt) do if %groceryrandom%==%%a echo %%b
```

Here is the text file its referencing

```
1 Nothing
2 Nothing
3 "You have gained 1 survivor!"
4 Nothing
5 Nothing
6 "You have lost 1 survivor!"
7 Nothing
8 Nothing
9 "You have gained 1 survivor!"
10 Nothing
11 Nothing
12 "You have found 1 weapon!"
13 Nothing
14 Nothing
15 "You have found 5 ammo!"
```

Comment: `tokens=1,2*` See `for /?`.

Comment: What happens if `%groceryrandom%`=`0`? And why not use, `for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (groceryevents.txt) do if %groceryrandom%==%%a echo %%b`

Comment: @Compo Should I remove the 15 line, and make it 0-14? and change the random to %%15?

Comment: @Nate, please refer to the answer you've accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More straight forward is directly selecting the line with findstr

```
@echo off
set /a groceryrandom=%random% %% 15 +1

for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('
    findstr /BC:"%groceryrandom% " groceryevents.txt
') do echo %%B
```

Sample runs:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54372977.cmd
Nothing

> Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54372977.cmd
"You have lost 1 survivor!"

> Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54372977.cmd
Nothing

> Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54372977.cmd
Nothing

> Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54372977.cmd
Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:

```
@echo off

set /a groceryrandom=%random%%%15 + 1
for /f "tokens=1* skip=%groceryrandom%" %%a in (groceryevents.txt) do echo %%~b & goto continue
:continue
```

I added a `0 Nothing` line in the data file...